# Getting out of Beta - Again

Tags: discussion

Every now and then we have a discussion about getting out of beta. So I thought it might be time to have one again.

My understanding is that all the Area 51 criteria no longer matter and the only important factor is to consistently hit at least 10 questions a day.

My sense is that has now happened, though perhaps not for long enough. So is there any news or next steps on this?

Lastly, the stack exchanges keep evolving. At this point, what concrete difference would there be from getting out of beta?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Frankly speaking, I have no idea how much the original criteria for getting out of beta matters and to what extent. I don't know a clear way of petitioning for the site to be brought out of Beta, sans maybe going into one of the private chatrooms like the Teacher's Lounge and asking about it directly. I've also never really had to contact anyone higher up from me to deal with problems, but only to ask for advice, and I've operated under the idea that if we wanted to get out of beta, it'd be one of those, "don't call us, we'll call you" type deals. I could be mistaken, and can inquire about this more if desired.

Edit: I've put up an inquiry, and will see if I get a response.

Here is a very related question that suggests the [concept of retirement is mostly a nominal thing at this point](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344427/is-there-a-complete-list-of-possible-staging-in-stack-exchange-network/344432#344432). So not sure what that means for us coming out of beta. Will keep you all posted.

Comment: Any word back on the inquiry?

Comment: Nothing from an admin yet. The general speculation seems to be that any new graduations are on hold for now.